# Mac OS/Unix get known when the content of Clipboard changed

Tags: macos, unix, clipboard

As far as I know ,It is easy to assess the content of clipboard in Mac OS by using "pbpaste" and "pbcopy". 
Howerer ,Is there any way to get known when  the content of Clipboard changed,Like a Notification.
Just do not want to Poll the clipboard all the time.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general mac architecture and not programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com as there are other pbcopy/pbpaste questions there.

Comment: @trojanfoe I disagree a bit, it you could register for an NSNotificationCenter notification, that would be totally in scope.